# Websocket client not closing gracefully

Tags: c++, websocket, boost, asio, crow

I followed this [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync/websocket_client_sync.cpp) to create a websocket client.

This is the class for that:

```
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>
class  WebsocketClient {
public:
    WebsocketClient(const std::string& hostname, const std::string& port, const std::string& url)
        : m_socket(m_io_context)
    {

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver{ m_io_context };
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(hostname, port);
        auto ep = boost::asio::connect(m_socket.next_layer(), results);
        auto host = hostname + std::string(":") + std::to_string(ep.port());
        m_socket.set_option(boost::beast::websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](boost::beast::websocket::request_type& req) {
                req.set(boost::beast::http::field::user_agent,
                        std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                        " websocket-client-coro");
            }));

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        m_socket.handshake(host, url);
    }

    std::string read() {
        boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
        m_socket.read(buffer);
        char* char_ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer.data().data());
        return std::string(char_ptr, buffer.size());
    }

    void send(const std::string message) {
        m_socket.write(boost::asio::buffer(message));
    }

void close() {

        if (m_socket.is_open()) {
            m_socket.close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal);
        }

        std::cout << "THIS IS NEVER PRINTED " << std::endl;

}

    ~WebsocketClient() {
        close();
        std::cout << "NEVER REACHED " << std::endl;
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_context m_io_context;
    boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> m_socket;
};
```

I use crowcpp to create a simple websocket server

```
int main() {
    crow::SimpleApp app;
    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/").websocket()
        .onaccept([](const crow::request& ) {
            return true;
        })
        .onopen([&](crow::websocket::connection& ) {
            std::cout << "CLIENT OPENED - Server "<< std::endl;
        })
        .onclose([&](crow::websocket::connection& , const std::string&) {
            std::cout << "Client CLOSED - Server "<< std::endl;
        });
    std::future<void> m_async_thread_server;

    m_async_thread_server = app
        .bindaddr("127.0.0.1")
        .signal_clear()
        .port(8080)
        .run_async();
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    auto client = WebsocketClient("127.0.0.1", "8080", "/");

  }
```

My question is really whether I explicitly invoke `client.close()` or let the destructor handle it , the problem remains that my thread never returns after             `m_socket.close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal);`
By doing a bit of debugging I see that the websocket client is waiting to receive a close header message from the server. By digging a bit into what CrowCpp does after receiving a close request I do see it sends out a close header message.

running the code I get following prints only:

> (2023-04-15 12:20:32) [INFO    ] Crow/1.0 server is running at
> http://127.0.0.1:8080 using 2 threads (2023-04-15 12:20:32) [INFO    ]
> Call `app.loglevel(crow::LogLevel::Warning)` to hide Info level logs.

> Client OPENED - Server

> Client CLOSED - Server

Comment: Oh. Did you mean that the server... "includes" the client. Nm then. That's confusing.

Comment: sorry, yes the namespaces should not have been there, They are removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the RFC:

> After both sending and receiving a Close message, an endpoint
> considers the WebSocket connection closed and MUST close the
> underlying TCP connection.  The server MUST close the underlying TCP
> connection immediately; the client SHOULD wait for the server to
> close the connection but MAY close the connection at any time after
> sending and receiving a Close message, e.g., if it has not received a
> TCP Close from the server in a reasonable time period.

The Crow server fails to close the connection upon replying to the close frame with its own one.

It keeps track of `close_connection_` when `has_recv_close_` as well as `has_sent_close_` are true.

However, only when Crow was the side sending the first close frame (and receiving the responding close frame from the peer), it will actually close the connection. This is apparently just not very well-tested.

### Fixing it

Starting from v1.0+5 release, edf12f699ec3bf6f751cf73c, I improved the unit test to show the problem, then fixed it, and you can see the problem going away.

***click to see higher quality***

> [image]

```
diff --git a/include/crow/websocket.h b/include/crow/websocket.h
index 4555b70d..037a92c2 100644
--- a/include/crow/websocket.h
+++ b/include/crow/websocket.h
@@ -582,10 +582,14 @@ namespace crow
                           sending_buffers_.clear();
                           if (!ec && !close_connection_)
                           {
-                              if (!write_buffers_.empty())
-                                  do_write();
                               if (has_sent_close_)
+                              {
                                   close_connection_ = true;
+                                  adaptor_.close();
+                                  check_destroy();
+                              }
+                              if (!write_buffers_.empty())
+                                  do_write();
                           }
                           else
                           {
```

Makes it run fine. The `master` branch is not compatible with your sample server, but appears to have the same problem still.

> Another problem around closing has been fixed since, though:
>
> ```
> ed87c65c|| Merge pull request #452 from MichaelSB/ws_no_read_after_close
> efee7174|| do not try to read from websocket after sending and receiving the close frame
> ```

Comment: Submitted the PR https://github.com/CrowCpp/Crow/pull/619, I cannot actually reproduce the original problem with latest master, but like I said your server.cpp is not compatible with that version of Crow.

Comment: in what why is not compatible?

Comment: @ATK You can find out the same way I had to find out what specific version I needed to use? https://imgur.com/a/GRs7p2m (gallery of steps), [client.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e5b4fba4e07f064), [server.cpp](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f4025e15c4a860b)